# With CMake, how can I use the same source for a library for multiple different builds

Tags: cmake

I'd need to find how to best use CMake to build multiple different versions of the same library.

Let's assume that I have software A, B and C. All of these use the same external library, let's call that D. Let's assume that D is huge compared to A, B & C. So just using svn:external to checkout it multiple times is a bad option.

What crossed my mind is to have a folder where I have the subfolders for A, B, C & D and just calling add_subdir(../D). But to make things complicated, I don't want to enforce this folder structure on other developers, so I ended up with the thought of making this work with find_package, somehow.

What I'd like to see is that you are able to get C and D from subversion to any folders and have C compile it's own version of D for itself and use it, with no effort from the custom folders.

This might seem like a silly dream, but not being the smartest man on the planet, maybe someone has an idea of how to achieve this.

EDIT:
note that A B & C cannot use the same binaries for D since they would use different compiler flags to build the library.

Comment: Since you cannot use binaries, `find_package` will not be the solution, because what it does is to help locate binary libraries to link to.

Comment: Also, are A, B and C part of a single CMake project, or are they independant of each other ?

Comment: They are completely independent.

Comment: SirDarius, When you write your own thing for the find_package to run, things are possible.

Comment: true, it is possible yeah, there are header only libraries too. In this case, I believe a simple cmake user-visible variable pointing at the source code root for D would work.

Comment: however, that would require input from the user. What I'd like is that this variable would be automatically retrieved, somehow. A post-checkout svn hook would be something, but that requires changes to svn client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`add_subdirectory`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_subdirectory) works with directories located outside the main project dir, you just have to give a `binary_dir`.

> **`add_subdirectory`**`(source_dir [binary_dir] [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL])`
>
> Add a subdirectory to the build. The `source_dir` specifies the directory in which the source CMakeLists.txt and code files are located. If it is a relative path it will be evaluated with respect to the current directory (the typical usage), **but it may also be an absolute path**. The `binary_dir` specifies the directory in which to place the output files. If it is a relative path it will be evaluated with respect to the current output directory, but it may also be an absolute path.

In A, B and C you could have something like that:

```
set(MYPROJECT_D_PATH "" CACHE PATH "Path to D")

if("${test}" STREQUAL "")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "You must set MYPROJECT_D_PATH")
endif()

add_subdirectory(${MYPROJECT_D_PATH} D)
```

When you compile A, B or C for the first time, you provides the path to D like that:

```
cmake <src_dir> -DMYPROJECT_D_PATH=<path_to_D>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought of using, but I'd like to provide the path_to_D through some form of magic. So that I'd not need to give it manually, manual changing of that path should be supported, but if it's not given, it would be found out automatically. Now the automatic find part is what puzzles me.

Comment: If you want to find it automatically and don't have any clue, you have to go through the whole hard drive to find D. It is obviously a bad idea. The usual way to solve this is to use environment variables and/or default search path. You can use `find_path` to do it easily with CMake.